# Subtraction of dates with hours and minutes (result in float)

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis, derived-column

I would like some help with an SSIS problem.

I have two columns, one with a date of when demand was open and another when the demand was responded to.

My date comes in this way:

| DT_ANSWERED_DATE | DT_CREATED_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-04 19:48:00.000 | 2021-02-04 19:44:00.000 |

I would like to subtract DT_ANSWERED_DATE ***MINUS*** DT_CREATED_DATE
but I would like the result would be a float number:

like in this case when a subtract in excel
I get the result:

| DT_ANSWERED_DATE | DT_CREATED_DATE | DT_ANSWERED_DATE minus DT_CREATED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-04 19:48:00.000 | 2021-02-04 19:44:00.000 | 0,00277777777228039 |

I would like to do the same thing but in a derived column at SSIS (Microsoft Visual Studio)

Thanks for the response in advance

Comment: Is there a reason the result needs to match Excel's numeric value of datetime? Looking at the logic for it, it's possible to match closely, but not perfect -- maybe 10 decimals.  How will the output be used and is the precision very important?

Comment: how about a datediff in milliseconds and then divide by however many milliseconds are in a day.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your granularity is in minutes. This should get you the decimal number you are looking for...

```
DATEDIFF("mi", DT_CREATED_DATE, DT_ANSWERED_DATE) / (60 * 24)
```

(60 min per hour * 24 hours in a day)

Microsoft documentation... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/datediff-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver16

In your example above this results in:

```
4 min / (60*24) = 0.00277777777
```

Note:
I highly recommend using decimal vs float. Unless you really, really have a reason. 1=1 is usually not true when using a float number. It will always be true with integers or decimals.

Comment: It actually makes the most sense to leave the answer in minutes and store it as minutesToAnswwer